# Static initialization of inherited static member

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, static-members

Consider this example code:

```
public class A<T> 
{
    public static T TheT { get; set; }
}
public class B : A<string>
{
    static B() {
        TheT = "Test";
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(B.TheT);
    }
}
```

Here `B.TheT` is null. However, changing the `Main` method like this:

```
public static void Main() {
    new B();
    Console.WriteLine(B.TheT);
}
```

`B.TheT` is "Test", as expected. I can understand that this forces the static constructor to run, but why does this not happen for the first case?

I tried reading the spec, and this caught my attention (§10.12):

> [...] The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the
>   following events to occur within an application domain:
>
> • [...]
>
> • Any of the static members of the class type are referenced.

My interpretation of this is that since `TheT` is not a member of `B`, the static constructor of `B` is not forced to be run. Is this correct?

If that is correct, how would I best let `B` specify how to initialize `TheT`?

Comment: As an aside, your example would be a lot clearer if you hadn't overloaded the name `A` by generic arity.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Good point. I'll give it another name (it sort of makes sense in the actual use as a shorthand, but here it might be a bit confusing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A.TheT is "Test", as expected. I can understand that this forces the static constructor to run, but why does this not happen for the first case?

Basically, you haven't *really* referenced `B`. If you look in the IL, I think you'll find that your code was actually equivalent to:

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine(A<string>.TheT);
}
```

The compiler worked out that that's *really* the member you meant, even though you wrote `B.TheT`.

> If that is correct, how would I best let A specify how to initialize TheT?

I would try to avoid doing this to start with, to be honest... but you could always just add a static method to `B`:

```
public static void Initialize() {
    // Type initializer will be executed now.
}
```

Comment: It gets more interesting when this is declared `public class B : A<int>
        {
            static B()
            {
                TheT = 5;
            }
        }`

Comment: Jon, are you sure about this? You do have an almost encyclopedic knowledge of the C# language spec so I usually defer to what you say, but I don't think the compiler will auto-guess the type argument of a class like that.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that was about my understanding (my decompiler actually showed my `Console.WriteLine(A<T>.TheT)`, which was sort of confusing). Regarding the `Initialize`, my hope was that I could make this somewhat automatic, so that whenever someone decided to use the non-generic shortcut class, `TheT` could be automatically initialized. I don't think that is possible with your suggested approach?

Comment: @DavidPfeffer: There's no guesswork involved - it knows that `A : A<string>`

Comment: @carlpett: No, I don't know of an easy way of doing this, and frankly using static initialization like this is *usually* a design smell IMO.

Comment: Shouldn't it have been "Basically, you haven't really referenced *B*"?

Comment: @fsimonazzi: I changed names in the example code, see the comments to the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet: It could be that this is a bad design, yes. I should probably ask another question about that rather than taking it in the comments, though. Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: @carlpett: I see, B used to be a non-generic A. I think it's worth editing Jon Skeet's answer to match the changes, as now it could be interpreted as A meaning the generic (and only) type in your question; it certainly happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

Static constructor is called before the first access or at the latest when the first access is made. I.e you know it has been called when first access is made but not how long before. However, if no access is made it won't be called. So you cannot control when only if it s called.

***As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reference***

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs performed once only. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

Answer (score 0):

In second case called static contructor and it will call the actual types' static contructor, and not that one of *derived* one. So in your case it calls the static ctor of the `A<T> =>A<string>` and **not** of `A`.

To prove this behaviour just do the following:

```
public class Base {

    static Base() {
      "Base static".Dump(); 
    }
}

public class Derived : Base {

    static Derived() {
      "Derived static".Dump(); 
    }

    public static string temp = "Hello";
}
```

and call

```
Derived.temp.Dump();
```

You will get:

```
Derived static
Hello
```

This is  what you actually do in your code, you acess *derived* type `A<string>` and it's default static ctor is called.