# Initializing inherited static properties

Tags: c#, inheritance

We have a class `IoC<TContainer>` where `TContainer` is a class wrapping whatever IoC container we use in the the module which includes the class. It is implemented like this:

```
public class IoC<TContainer>
    where TContainer : IServiceLocator
{
    public static TContainer Container { get; set; }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<T>();
    }
    public static object Resolve(Type type)
    {
        return Container.Resolve(type);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> ResolveAll<T>()
    {
        return Container.ResolveAll<T>();
    }
    public static IEnumerable ResolveAll(Type type)
    {
        return Container.ResolveAll(type);
    }
}
```

Currently, somewhere it needs to be initialized like this

```
IoC<StructureMapServiceLocator>.Container = ...
```

To simplify usage, I tried to define a class like this:

```
public class SMIoC : IoC<StructureMapServiceLocator>
{
    private SMIoC()
    {}

    static SMIoC()
    {
        Container = ... // Initialization
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work ([Earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953797)), and it was suggested that this is a bad design. How can I either automate the initialization (using the static constructor or with some other method), or some other trick?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do that in application during application or service intialization:

- *ASP.NET*. Global.asax `Application_Start` event or a custom HTTP module.
- *Web API*. Same as ASP.NET.
- Windows Forms / WPF / Silverlight...... `Main()`
- ...

I wouldn't rely on a static constructor. If you need to be sure that your container got assigned for any request or thread, I prefer what I explained above because each platform gives a method override, event or whatever that's executed during framework initialization *(that's a single thread will be working at the moment of instantiating the container and setting it to some static property, while other threads will be blocked until initialization has ended)*.

Finally, there's no generic, platform-agnostic **safe** way of setting *inversion of control* container to a static property. In order to be sure that things are done right, take the hint! :)